# Добавление объектов в файл .json с новой строки

Tags: python, json, файлы, форматирование, данные

У меня данные в формате `"айди пользователя": "данные"` заносятся в JSON файл, но заносятся они все в одну строчку: `{"123456789": "ru", "987654321": "en"}`, а хочу, чтобы заносились так:

```
{
    "123456789": "ru",
    "987654321": "en"
}
```

Вот кусок моего кода:

```py
with open("users.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(user_data, file)
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, с данной "проблемой", ибо я еще совсем зеленый. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметр `indent`

```
json.dump(user_data, file, indent=4)
```